# How to disable buttons if status is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects `[{name:'a',status:1},{name:'b',status:0},{name:'c',status:0}]`. I am rendering buttons through `.map()`. What I want to achieve is if status===1 then I want to enable current button (not enable buttons that have status 0) and if status === 0, I want to disable all the buttons having status of 0.

I implemented a logic that is working fine but I have an issue with if `name:a` status changes to `0`, it disables all buttons.

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

**code**

```
<button disabled = {item.status===1?true:false} />
```

Comment: can you share more of the code? This will work fine provided `item` is the argument to the function passed to the `map` method - so it sounds like something is slightly off there, but you don't show it. PS `item.status===1?true:false` is the same as, and should be rewritten as, just `item.status===1`.

Comment: can you share more understandable code so can give the answer